# how to store passwords for an iOS app like the iOS mail app

Tags: ios, passwords

I want to store username and password for my app in a similar way iOS mail app does. Its like go to setting and choose the mail setting and store the username and password. So when the iOS mail app is opened the user is automatically authenticated using the credentials given in the setting. 
Can anyone let me know how can I programmatically achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have already checked the other answer but what I actually need is to accomplish username/password saves using the iOS settings like the mail app. The ways you are proposing is just to save passwords but what I need is how to program the saving of passwords in settings in iOS. Also through the setting how to you store it to the keychain ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want to know how to mak settings for your application appear in the global iPhone settings application?
Then in your Xcode projekt make **"File / New / iOS / Resource / Settings Bundle"**

And then read some tutorial like:

- http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/05/18/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app.html
- http://sugartin.info/2012/08/16/application-settings-bundle-part-i/

If this puts you on the right track, please mark question solved.
Otherwise please add more details to your question.

Comment: Yes I mean that but also I need to store the username/password and have a server information setup there so that everytime I access the app it gets the username and password from this setting and does the authentication. So its not only setting but also authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You should be saving passwords to the KeyChain. There are plenty of 3rd party Keychain libraries...here are a couple

- https://github.com/carlbrown/PDKeychainBindingsController
- https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security